# How to Group same field under one field using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have following table with data

```
emp_no  emp_name        login  HOD_code  Level  
E43057  Ankita Barde     9:45  P00212    Direct 
E33995  Rakesh Sharma    8:15  P00212    Direct 
E31446  Amit Singh      10:45  P00212    Direct 
E44920  Shweta Salve     9:38  E33995    Indirect   
E39787  Anita Shenoy     9:15  E31446    Indirect   
E37731  Ramesh Shukla    9:10  E31446    Indirect   
E43455  Manish Shukla   11:01  E33995    Indirect   
E43130  Lubna Shaikh     9:39  E33995    Indirect
```

In the above table I have one HOD code (P00212) superior to all so employee which are mapped under P00212 are specified as direct employee in the LEVEL column and all others are indirect to P00212. But this indirect employees are mapped under Direct Employee
For eg:  P00212 is HOD of Rakesh Sharma (E33995) and E33995 is HOD of 3 other employe i.e Shweta(E44920), E43455, E43130. So I want to write a query in such way that the output will look like the following

OUTPUT:

```
emp_no  emp_name        login  HOD_NO  Level    
E43057  Ankita Barde     9:45  P00212  Direct

E33995  Rakesh Sharma    8:15  P00212  Direct   
E43455  Manish Shukla   11:01  E33995  Indirect 
E43130  Lubna Shaikh     9:39  E33995  Indirect 
E44920  Shweta Salve     9:38  E33995  Indirect

E31446  Amit Singh      10:45  P00212  Direct   
E39787  Anita  Shenoy    9:15  E31446  Indirect 
E37731  Ramesh Shukla    9:10  E31446  Indirect
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eb9fa/4)

```
select * from t
order by CASE WHEN HOD_CODE='P00212' THEN EMP_NO ELSE HOD_CODE END,
         CASE WHEN HOD_CODE='P00212' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: thanks it worked..i got my solution ...can you please explain how exactly it is working!!!thanks alot :)

Comment: @shweta: First we order by HOD_CODE but for P00212 we get not HOD_CODE but emp_no. So we group records as we need it. In the second sort expression we order records inside the group and if it is P00212 we place it on the top.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
select 
    *, 
    case 
        when (HOD_CODE='P00212') 
        then emp_no 
        else HOD_code 
    end as Parent
from Table
Order by Parent, Emp_No
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ee9/9)